# Ansible EC2 No such file or directory: b'ssh': b'ssh'

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, ssh, ansible

I am trying to deploy dockerized react web app to EC2 but I am still getting an error when configuring the instance. Already search but did not find anything.

Deploying using command:

```
ansible-playbook -vvvvv ansible/ec2_deploy.yml --user ubuntu
```

Docker which I am running ansible in:

```
FROM node:10.23.0-alpine3.9
COPY . .
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN apk add --update --no-cache python3 && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN python3 -m ensurepip
RUN pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools
RUN apk add --update ansible
RUN apk add 
RUN pip install boto
RUN chmod 777 get_vault_pass.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh" ]
```

Ansible deployment:

```
- name: Deploy to EC2
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - name: Launch EC2 instance
      ec2:
        instance_type: t2.micro
        image: ami-0885b1f6bd170450c
        region: us-east-1
        key_name: eshop-key-pair
        vpc_subnet_id: subnet-cafc34fb
        assign_public_ip: yes
        wait: yes
        count: 1
        group: eshop
        aws_access_key: 'key'
        aws_secret_key: 'key2'
        security_token: 'token'
      register: ec2

    - name: Add instance host to group
      add_host: hostname={{ item.public_dns_name }} groupname=launched
      with_items: '{{ec2.instances}}'

    - name: Wait for SSH connection
      wait_for: host={{ item.public_dns_name }} port=22 delay=60 timeout=600 state=started
      with_items: '{{ec2.instances}}'

- name: Configure EC2
  hosts: launched
  connection: ssh

  tasks:
    - name: Install docker
      apt:
        name: docker.io
        state: present
        update_cache: yes
      become: yes
    - service:
        name: docker
        state: started
        enabled: yes
      become: yes
    - name: Get project files from GIT
      git: 
        repo: 'https://github.com/romanzdk/4IT572_ZS_2020_circleci.git'
        dest: ./app
    - name: Build docker with eshop
      shell: cd app && docker build -t myeshop:latest .
      become: yes
    - name: Run docker with eshop
      shell: docker run -p 80:3000 myeshop
      async: 90
      poll: 15
      become: yes
    - wait_for: delay=60 timeout=600
      port: 80
```

Stack trace:

```
PLAY [Configure EC2] ***********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************************************************
task path: /ansible/ec2_deploy.yml:30
<ec2-100-25-28-7.compute-1.amazonaws.com> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<ec2-100-25-28-7.compute-1.amazonaws.com> SSH: ansible.cfg set ssh_args: (-C)(-o)(ControlMaster=auto)(-o)(ControlPersist=60s)
<ec2-100-25-28-7.compute-1.amazonaws.com> SSH: ansible_password/ansible_ssh_pass not set: (-o)(KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no)(-o)(PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey)(-o)(PasswordAuthentication=no)
<ec2-100-25-28-7.compute-1.amazonaws.com> SSH: ANSIBLE_TIMEOUT/timeout set: (-o)(ConnectTimeout=10)
<ec2-100-25-28-7.compute-1.amazonaws.com> SSH: found only ControlPersist; added ControlPath: (-o)(ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/aaee2dc684)
<ec2-100-25-28-7.compute-1.amazonaws.com> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/aaee2dc684 ec2-100-25-28-7.compute-1.amazonaws.com '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 140, in run
    res = self._execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 612, in _execute
    result = self._handler.run(task_vars=variables)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/action/normal.py", line 46, in run
    result = merge_hash(result, self._execute_module(task_vars=task_vars, wrap_async=wrap_async))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/action/__init__.py", line 745, in _execute_module
    self._make_tmp_path()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/action/__init__.py", line 294, in _make_tmp_path
    tmpdir = self._remote_expand_user(tmpdir, sudoable=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/action/__init__.py", line 613, in _remote_expand_user
    data = self._low_level_execute_command(cmd, sudoable=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/action/__init__.py", line 980, in _low_level_execute_command
    rc, stdout, stderr = self._connection.exec_command(cmd, in_data=in_data, sudoable=sudoable)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/ssh.py", line 1145, in exec_command
    (returncode, stdout, stderr) = self._run(cmd, in_data, sudoable=sudoable)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/ssh.py", line 392, in wrapped
    return_tuple = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/ssh.py", line 1035, in _run
    return self._bare_run(cmd, in_data, sudoable=sudoable, checkrc=checkrc)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/ssh.py", line 790, in _bare_run
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'ssh': b'ssh'

fatal: [ec2-52-73-248-179.compute-1.amazonaws.com]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.",
    "stdout": ""
}
```

Any idea what is wrong? I already spent an ages on this...
here is some more text as I am asked to add more details because of the long code, lol

Comment: `ansible` uses `ssh`; it doesn't appear that `ssh` was installed in the Docker image. (That seems surprising, as I would assume that the `ansible` package would pull `ssh` in as a prerequisite.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

chepner's comment is spot on - your docker image doesn't have `ssh` installed. Try

```
apk add openssh-client
```

and the error should be solved.

Comment: omg, yeah, that was it. i thought ssh is "standard" and if it does not come with alpine itself or python, the it would come with ansible, but... does not seems to be true... thank you!

Comment: The error message doesn't help - when I ran into this I thought Ansible just couldn't find the SSH key!